# Positioning a Material UI button to the rightmost of row

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Trying to align this React material-ui button to the right-most of the page and can't seem to get this working:

```
    <Grid item justify="flex-end">
      <Button              
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={() => myFunction()}
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Grid>
```

Have tried `justify="flex-end"` but doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Put your all of your code here. Also you will get help a lot quicker if you can provide a CodeSandbox so others can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `justify=` goes on the `container` instead of the `item`, like this:

```
<Grid container justify="flex-end">
  <Grid item>
    <Button              
      variant="contained"
      color="primary"
      onClick={() => myFunction()}
    >
      Submit
    </Button>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me.

```
<Box display="flex" justifyContent="flex-end">
  <Button              
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    onClick={() => myFunction()}
  >
    Submit
  </Button>
</Box>
```

If you want to use Grid, please use inline style like this.

```
 <Grid item style={{display:"flex"}} justify="flex-end">
          <Button              
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            onClick={() => myFunction()}
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Added this code to `<Grid item display="flex" justifyContent="flex-end">` and unfortunately made no difference.

Comment: if you want to use Grid, please use inline style. I edited my answer.